# Process Types and names

Tags: software-engineering

There seems to be a classification of processes in IT. For example, "business process" refers to the collection of tasks done by organization members / software systems to achieve a goal.

If a process is completely automated and carried out by software (no people involved) what is the process called? Say we have a Web service A and service B online and we have a process that automatically uses both in achieving a goal.

I googled for "Software process" but the results are not what I am looking for (e.g waterfall)

My apologies if this is not the correct forum to ask this question.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Business process" can also be applied.  Or you could call it "automated process" or "automated business process" or "software processing" or "service" or any of a number of other things.

In other words: these terms do not have a precise mathematical/technical definition.  So, define your terms, and use them consistently.  This is not a technical question (and this site is better-suited for technical questions, not terminology questions).